# Merging separately created imputed datasets (mice)

Tags: r, list, data.table, imputation, r-mice

Because my computer barely handles the imputation process of a big dataset, I decided to separately create the imputations. An example looks as follows:

```
df = data.table(A = c(1, 1, 2, 2), B = c(NA, 2, 2, 1), C = c(3, 3, 2, 2), D=c(4, 4, 2, 2))
tab
    A  B  C  D
1:  1  NA  3  4
2:  1  2  3  4
3:  2  2  2  2
4:  2  1  2  2 

dfmice1 <- mice(df, m=1, maxit = 5, method='cart')
save.image()
rm(dfmice1)
dfmice2 <- mice(df, m=1, maxit = 5, method='cart')
```

Now I want to add these datasets together in the same `mice` "environment", as they would have been when I simply did:

```
dfmice <- mice(df, m=2, maxit = 5, method='cart')
```

Could someone help to explain how to do this?

Comment: why not running mice() by group? e.g.  `df[, mice_out = list(mice(df, m=1, maxit = 5, method='cart') ), by = grp] `

Comment: Thank you for your comment! Firstly, because I already ran it. Secondly, because the point is to empty the workspace between runs.

Comment: Also, I am fairly sure that the expected values of the predictions will not be identical..